# MacOS Automator asks for permission every time

Tags: macos, automator

I have an Automator script running on my Mac that, every Saturday at midnight, collects the data from my calendar and exports it to a txt file on my network drive.  I have a linux computer that will, five minutes later, go to that location and do something with the data.

When midnight arrives on Saturday, however, I find that my Mac is trying to get my permission for Automator to access my calendar, contacts, and network drive.  Even after I gave it these permissions, it still prompts me to run the program before it executes.  Since I am dealing with time data, and the timing of the program's execution is important, is it possible to give automator some privileges in this regard?

I added a caffeinate script command to run before the program to prevent the computer from going to sleep, but this does not change the need for actively activating the time data script.

Comment: Is something in the workflow or application bundle getting changed?